# An electricity experiment

Tags: laws-of-physics

Ohms law can be sated as V=IR.
a. Suppose in an experiment, data is collected of the variation of current with
resistance R. Next a plot of R vs I
-1 is made. How does one determine the 
value of V from that graph.

Comment: This sounds like a standard practical for finding the emf $\mathcal E$ and internal resistance of a cell $r$ with $\mathcal E = I(r+R) \Rightarrow R= \mathcal E I^{-1} -r$. From the graph of $R$ against $I^{-1}$ the two unknowns can be found.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to plot different points of (R, 1/I) and then solve for I and then multiply R by I to get V. I don’t believe there is any other way...